# how to handle the result of dialog box that allow user to enable location without leaving the app

Tags: android

**Query 1** :I am checking user's location at the splash screen if location is not enabled the there is a prompt that will enable user's location without leaving the app. but when the prompt displayed it is not waiting for user's response (yes/no). for this i have to handle the prompt result into some method so that according to the user's response rest of the code will execute. i have tried this using onActivityresult() method but no luck because first it requires to call startActivityForResult()and it takes the intent as one of its parameter( in my code there is no need for user to navigation phone location setting once user will say yes location will enable automatically). i want to execute the code after user click yes.

**Query2** when the dialog box displayed i want the splash screen to run in backgroud.

**splash screen**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 Boolean b1=    locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    LocationManager locationManager1 = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Boolean b2=locationManager1.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (!b1&&!b2) {
        startLocationAlert = new StartLocationAlert(this);
        Boolean b3=startLocationAlert.settingsrequest();
    } else {
        startActivityThread();
    }
}
public void startActivityThread(){
    final Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent intent = null;
                boolean loggedIn = false;
                SharedPreferences w = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor share = w.edit();
                loggedIn = (w.getBoolean("loggedIn", loggedIn));
                System.out.println("logged in " + loggedIn);
                if (loggedIn) {
                    intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TestNavigationFragments.class);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

**StartLocationAlert**

```
Activity context;
boolean result1=false;
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
public StartLocationAlert(Activity context) {
    this.context = context;
    googleApiClient = getInstance();

    if(googleApiClient != null){
        settingsrequest();
        googleApiClient.connect();
        result1=true;

    }
}
public  GoogleApiClient getInstance(){
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}
public boolean settingsrequest()
{
    Log.e("settingsrequest","Comes");
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    result1=true;
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(context, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.e("Applicationsett",e.toString());
                    }
                    result1=true;
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Location is Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    result1=true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    return result1;
}
```